# hql distinct order

Tags: sql-order-by, hql, distinct

Hi i need to select distinct objects ordered by the newest subobject, how can i do this?
i tried to select the parent-objects from the subobjects:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.forumTheme FROM ForumResponse r ORDER BY r.responseId DESC
```

i get

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

and when i try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.forumTheme,r.responseId FROM ForumResponse r ORDER BY r.responseId DESC
```

the result isnt really distinct: forumTheme can appear multible times with different responseId

is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given forumTheme, you have several responseIds. So how should they be sorted? Is `[6, 3, 2]` greater or lower than `[5, 4, 2]`?

This is why you can't do this order by.

You should probably execute the following query:

```
select r.forumTheme, max(r.responseId) from ForumResponse r 
group by r.forumTheme
order by max(r.responseId)
```

Comment: it should create the joined lines, order them by the responseId and kill the duplicate forumTehmes. When i try your solution i come to "ERROR: Column »forumtheme1_.themenid« has to be in GROUP-BY".

Comment: I thought forumTheme was a simple column, not an associated entity. See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1615?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#action_29485 for workarounds of this Hibernate bug.

Comment: The bug is a related to group by. Your original query is still invalid.